# How to set number of columns in GridView according to minimal and maximal column width?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I have a `GridView` in my layout that should take up as much space as available (all other elements of the layout have a fixed size).

I want all the `Views` in the cells of the `GridView` to take up as much width as possible, i.e. not leaving any additional space except the spacing defined by the `GridView`.

I want the number of columns of the `GridView`to be automatically determined by the following constraints:

- The minimal column width should be `200dp` (unless the grid view itself is smaller)
- The maximal column width should be `300dp`
- I always want the highest number of columns that fit these constraints.

For this android needs to determine the right number of columns somehow by itself (`auto_fit` defaults to 2 if the cell width is unknown). The problem is that my implementation of `ListAdapter` delivering the cell `Views` with `getView()` must deliver views of the right size before the width of the grid view is known (`parent.getWidth()` will return 0 initially).

So during the layout phase the width of the grid view is not yet known, but still the grid view already wants to know the number of columns. For determining the number of columns according to my constraints however I must know the width of the grid view (and since it is taking up all available space anyway this should be possible to know).

Also one can set a minimal width and height on `Views` but this seems not to help with column widths of a grid view.

So how can I enforce all these constraints programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it was much easier than I had thought in the beginning.

Android does it more or less automatically for you, if you:

- set `android:numColumns="auto_fit" android:stretchMode="columnWidth"` in the layout of the grid view and
- set `android:minWidth="200dp"` in the layout of the views used for the grid view cells and
- set `android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"` in both

This means that each column must be at least 200 dp and android will determine the number of columns so that the maximal number of columns with a column width of at least 200 dp is set and if the column are wider it will stretch the cells (evenly).

I had more complicated solutions involving `getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener()` to wait until the grid view had determined it's size than calculating the number of columns by myself and then setting an `Adapter` but the solution above was identical in result and much less effort.